# Simplest way to get Laravel "Hello World" going?

Tags: laravel

I have programmed in PHP for many years, but it was before frameworks like Laravel. I am trying to understand Laravel now.

Can someone point me to something that explains the simplest possible way to get a Laravel "Hello World" app running. I know how to use composer. I have a Linux shared hosting account I can use for this.

I'd appreciate if someone could explain how I can get a simple Laravel example up and running, without having to install a ton of stuff on my PC.
Thanks.

Comment: This article will be really useful if want to know the basics -> [Click here](https://www.codementor.io/syedikramshah/step-by-step-guide-to-building-your-first-laravel-application-9sd0fttcc). Btw, you can also find a lot of beginner and advanced laravel tutorial video series on youtube.

Comment: You can learn all the basics with the documentation of Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Using composer download the latest version of laravel. Documentation is available at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel hello
```

After that go to that directory

```
cd hello
```

and run this command

```
php artisan server
```

Now open the browser and go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/
You will get a basic page that says Laravel and some links

Open hello with your code editor and open this file resources/views/welcome.blade.php

Write some content on the page and check  http://127.0.0.1:8000/

You can watch the https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018 to get a basic idea.

(Optional) If you are in windows you can use https://laragon.org/ in that the installation is pretty easy.

---

To run this app on shared hosting.

First,

1) Create a folder Application on your file manager

2) Upload files to that folder. (Laravel files, installed via composer)

3) Move public folder files to /public_html/ if you want the site in root domain

4) open index.php file and edit these lines

```
require __DIR__.'/Application/vendor/autoload.php';
....
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/Application/bootstrap/app.php';
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. 2 questions: a) On LInux shared hosting I'd need to point my browser to something other than http://127.0.0.1:8000/ right? I don't think I'd have access to that URL on shared hosting. Would I be able to set it up so I can point my browser to something like http://example.com/laravel-test ? Or would I have to do these steps you've outlined locally on my Windows PC instead? b) The downloading part...is that what your first line above does (`composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel hello`), it downloads the latest version?

Comment: Is it easy for you to test the app on local and upload to shared hosting?

Comment: Yes. it will download the latest version of laravel. I have updated the answer for uploading to shared hosting. if you want the domain to be example.com/laravel-test upload the public contents to that directory and edit the index.php files correctly.

Comment: Step 2 above ("Upload file to that folder...") I can SSH into my shared hosting account (with putty) so I can just run the commands you've listed to install directly on hosting account, right? I wouldn't need to upload from the PC, right? (Sorry...Laravel newbie)

Comment: If you have shell access just run the compose command. It will download the laravel files. No need to upload files  . Then follow other steps. :)

Comment: keep getting errors  relating to those lines in index.php. What should I edit them to be? [I have a 'laravel' subdomain set up on my host, laravel.mydomain.com, and I have installed Laravel into a 'laravel-test' directory one level up from that (but outside the web root)]

Comment: If one level up then the lines will be like this. require __DIR__.'/../laravel-test/vendor/autoload.php';
....
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../laravel-test/bootstrap/app.php';